Identify Textures/Materials?
I was given some blender env assets by a friend to use in Daz. I was told to just import the obj and set the textures up. Sure,  thats easy because Daz Iray used Principled BSDF as it's shader... Yeah it wasn't so easy. I know what the Diffuse color texture is as well as the normal map but these two, I've no idea what they are or what they do. I tried asked over on the daz forums but no one there knew. And, since the asset's meant for Blender I figured I'd ask here.
And if it helps the first (small one) is named MEDI_WallTileHospital_E and the second one is named MEDI_WallTileHospita_M



In PBR maps (Physically Based Rendering), there are diffuse, normal, roughness, displacement, metallic and ambient occlusion maps. Could _E be elevation/displacement and _M metallic ? Or _M could be for "mortar" as it looks like a mask...

It didnt work as a mask but using the M with the metallic setting worked wonderfully as did the E for displacement. ty!
